# phpunit ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object (Laravel/Entrust project)

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, entrust

When I run phpunit on my Laravel based project I get an error:
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object

But only on phpunit, the page renders fine.

This is the line of code in my blade template that is de cause of the error:

```
{{ $user->roles->first()->display_name }}
```

When I replace this with the following (ugly) code the phpunit tests run ok:

```
@php ($role = preg_replace('/[^a-z\d ]/i', '', $user->roles->pluck('display_name')) ) 
{{ $role }}
```

The roles are eager loaded in the controller:

```
$users->load('roles');
```

Any idea why phpunit throws this error (and laravel  not) and how to sove this in a better way?

Stacktrace from phpunit: https://paste.ee/p/dyMVs#

Comment: what are the output of {{ $user->roles }} and of  {{ $user->roles->count() }} ?

Comment: Hi Yohanan, {{ $user ->roles }} outputs:  [{"id":1,"name":"Admin","display_name":"Admin","description":"System administrator.","removable":false,"created_at":"2016-10-20 11:43:11","updated_at":"2016-10-20 11:43:11","pivot":{"user_id":3,"role_id":1}}]  and ->count() all returns 1

Comment: Just {{ $user->roles->pluck('display_name') }} also works but outputs ["Admin"]

Comment: I think the problem is that the role youre getting is an json object and not a collection.. try to see if it's converted to something else than a collection.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same idea but the strange thing is that collection methods seem to work.